# Managing HTML <input> history with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, input

Is there some way to manage <input> element's history using jQuery? (Saying "history", I don't mean autocomplete, I mena actually history, through which you can move using Ctrl+Z and Ctrl+Y).

Particularly I have an "erase" button near the field and i'd like to be able to undo changes with Ctrl+Z (I could do this myself, but just wondering if there is a built in way to modify the input's history)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You can first store the `<input>` data on browser localstorage then show data from there as history(later remove with ctrl+z, etc). You can also store localstorage data in a remote database.